# Function returning varchar inside select

Tags: plsql, oracle11g

Trying to generalize the SQL what splits a string/varchar into records. Here is the working SQL:

```
SELECT test.* FROM test JOIN (
SELECT level nbr, REGEXP_SUBSTR('1,3', '(.*?)(,|$)', 1, level, NULL, 1) value
FROM dual CONNECT BY level <= REGEXP_COUNT('1,3', ',')+1 ORDER BY level
) requested ON test.id=requested.value
```

What I mean by generalizing is; moving the recurring SQL (in this case the bit between the parenthesis's  from the working SQL above) to a procedure/function so it can be reused. In this case I'm trying to find a way to insert a generated inner select statement. This is how the generalized SQL may look like:

```
SELECT t.* FROM table t JOIN (<GENERATED_INNER_SELECT>) my ON t.x=my.x;
```

However I didn't succeed yet, I tried tho but calling my function to generate the inner select statement directly resulted in:

> ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement

And using the function in the generalized SQL resulted in:

> ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis

None of these errors make any sense to me in this context.

Perhaps you can help? [check out the full case on dbfiddle](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=05d606a06b1d8e3eb8ef56b3f9a8c1ef).

Comment: You can't make use a generated inner select unless the whole statement is executed dynamically. What you are really trying to do is find rows in `test` whose IDs are in your comma-separate string, right? Where is that string coming from? (I'm partly wondering if whatever calls this can supply it as a collection instead...)

Comment: @AlexPoole yes that's correct. The string is coming from a hidden field what gathers id's based on what row were checked.

Comment: Perhaps there is a way to do this via PL/SQL code instead of via a SQL query?

Comment: @Fleuv You could perhaps define a view that pulls out the data, and then use that in your sql statement? Alternatively, you could create a function that returns a nested table array (which is defined at the database level), and then select from that, e.g. `select * from table(some_function_returning_nested_table)`. Personally, I think the view is the better way to go with this, but YMMV.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you generate a SQL fragment to use as a subquery then the overall statement that embeds that as a subquery would have to be executed dynamically too.

It would be simpler to have the function actually doing the split itself, and returning a collection - as a schema-level collection type:

```
CREATE TYPE T_NUMBERS AS TABLE OF NUMBER
/

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION split(p_string VARCHAR2, p_seperator VARCHAR2 DEFAULT ',')
    RETURN T_NUMBERS AS
    L_NUMBERS T_NUMBERS;
BEGIN
    SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(p_string, '(.*?)(,|$)', 1, level, NULL, 1)
    BULK COLLECT INTO L_NUMBERS
    FROM dual
    CONNECT BY level <= REGEXP_COUNT(p_string, ',')+1;

    RETURN L_NUMBERS;
END split;
/

SELECT * FROM TEST
WHERE id MEMBER OF (split('1,3'))
/

        ID NAM
---------- ---
         1 foo
         3 foe
```

or if you prefer the table collection expression approach:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM TABLE(split('1,3')) tmp
JOIN test t ON t.id = tmp.column_value;
```

---

It would be even simpler if the query could be called with a collection of numbers in the first place, but without seeing how the call is being made - and the string generated - it's hard to say exactly how you'd need to change that. You could even use a built-in collection type then, instead of having to define your own:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM TABLE(SYS.ODCINUMBERLIST(1,3)) tmp
JOIN test t ON t.id = tmp.column_value;
```

but it relies on the caller being able to pass the numbers in rather than a string (note the lack of single quotes...)